# Modify selector to only target a specific tag [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, navigation

Code below will target all anchor link in wordpress navigation menu to have new attribute 'data-foo' with value 'bar'. How can it modified to only target a menu with specific class?

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', function( $item ) {

   $parts = explode( '>', $item );
   $out   = array ();    

   foreach ( $parts as $i => $part )
   {
      if ( 0 === strpos( $part, '<a ' ) ) // a start
         $out[ $i ] = $part . ' data-foo="bar"';
         else
         $out[ $i ] = $part;
   }

   return join( '>', $out );
});
```

Comment: This is in PHP, not JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In your code "walker_nav_menu_start_el" is a pre-defined "filter". You can use $get_body_class(className) to apply the filter to only elements with this class.

```
$class = $get_body_class('yourClassNameHere');

add_filter( $class, function( $item ) {

   $parts = explode( '>', $item );
   $out   = array ();    

   foreach ( $parts as $i => $part )
   {
      if ( 0 === strpos( $part, '<a ' ) ) // a start
         $out[ $i ] = $part . ' data-foo="bar"';
         else
         $out[ $i ] = $part;
   }

   return join( '>', $out );
});
```

Comment: If I modified the code with yours (placed in theme functions.php), the page will blank with NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I may have goofed it up a bit, add_filter might only except a string where get_body_class produces an array.